# How to make two picture equal height?

Tags: html, css

When my pictures with equal height, but when make img `width: 100%;`,things went wrong.the picture can't equal height.

I don't think this is an easy question to me.

I don't understand why picture with same height, can't render by browser equal height.

here is jsfindle.

[the effect with no pictures](http://jsfiddle.net/BJZ9e/)

But when I put pictures to img:src, things got bad.

After all, I want it make equal view though different device,not only pc.But,...

[image: view with chrome]

I puzzled, what's the point to this question?

Comment: You are reducing height of each img thats the reason.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you set the height of the FRAME to 35 and that doesn't change from one div to the next. The height is not set for the image in the CSS, but the MAX-HEIGHT is, so the height can be changed, but will not go over the max-height. Same with the width, it is not set.

When you change the height in the html tag, html keeps the restraints of the image size. If you remove 20 percent of the height, it will automatically remove 20 percent of the width unless you tell it not to by setting the width you want.

Try this:

```
<div class="frame">
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height="250" width="250" />
</div>
<div class="frame">
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height="25" width="250" />
</div>
```

The height will change, but the width will not. But of course the width has it's MAX-WIDTH set to 160px so even though this html code says 250, it still wont go over 160.

I think this is what you were asking, if not, then I apologize.

Comment: My question is not the picture's height,thanks!Can you read it again,please!

Comment: One big thing to note before going any further is that your CSS file is using the ID symbol (#) but your html is using the CLASS type (.). Try one of the other of the following. ONLY ONE. In your CSS file, change all # to . or in your HTML change all of you class= to id=

Comment: Also to note, you said you want to change the size of the img, but the only CSS you have on the image is no border and width:100% and the last one for width:100% a nd max-width:100%. You have to set the height of the image otherwise it will scale and use the image's max width, and max height. CSS is procedural, so the styling that runs overwrites the ones before it. In that last CSS add any height and see if that is what your looking for. height:100px;

Comment: I don't think the wrong is not id,and the `max-width` is only just for test.

Comment: # = id, and . = class. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp max-width is fine, but you are also setting the width and that scales the height. set the height and see if it changes

Comment: last week, i fix this question.I <img src="" width="100%" height="100">,after that in my js file, I use clientHeight to set the element in the same height.